# i am trying to align images horizontally with a link underneath each image. but every time i add a link, it goes all wrong

Tags: image, hyperlink, alignment

i want to add images on my website with a link underneath each image. i wanted them to be put horizontally. but instead of the link being underneath the image, it is next to it. i tried everything i could do, but it's not working. it was fine until i added a second image with a link. i have tried everything i can, also using css, but the aligment in not right. i tried finding the solution on the internet, but i could not find a solution to my problem. so i thought i could ask someone to help me.